# Need an algorithm to detect large spikes in oscillating data

Tags: c, algorithm, embedded, signal-processing

I am parsing through data on an sd card one large chunk at a time on a microcontroller. It is accelerometer data so it is oscillating constantly. At certain points huge oscillations occur (shown in graph). I need an algorithm to be able to detect these large oscillations, more so, determine the range of data that contains this spike.

I have some example data:

[image: Overall graph]
This is the overall graph, there is only one spike of interest, the first one.

[image: zoomed in]
Here it is zoomed in a bit

[image: oscillation]
As you can see it is a large oscillation that produces the spike.

So any algorithm that can scan through a data set and determine the portion of data that contains a spike relative to some threshold would be great. This data set is about 50,000 samples, each sample is 32 bits long. I have ample RAM to be able to hold this much data.

Thanks!

Comment: You could possibly use the differential part of a PID algorithm to determine what is a spike.

Comment: Currently taking the difference of two consecutive values and using that as some sort of metric, probably similar to what you mentioned

Comment: Simple detection would look for positive and negative excursions within a short time period, e.g. samples above 1.0 and below -1.0 within time 0.2.

Comment: I see that your data is already centered on zero. If the width of the spike is consistent and predictable, why not take the average of the modulus of a few samples. You could then threshold it to detect a spike. Maybe you could also use a sliding window to add a bit more reliability to it

Comment: This may be an X-Y question - to what purpose are you putting this "spike detection"?  What causes the spikes? Is it a phenomena caused by some acceleration you need to detect, or is it rather a signal you want to reject? If the latter then a low-pass IIR filter would be more appropriate. Looks like the kind of signal you might get from tapping the accelerometer.  Moreover if you are integrating the samples to get velocity, or double-integrating to get displacement, then these disturbances are likely to have no impact since they appear to be short lived and balanced around the steady-state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the following signal:

[image]

If you take the absolute value of the differential between two consecutive samples, you get:

[image]

That is not quite good enough to unambiguously distinguish from the minor "unsustained" disturbances.  But if you then take a simple *moving sum* (a leaky integrator) of the abs-differentials.  Here a window width of 4 diff-samples was used:

[image]

The moving average introduces a lag or phase shift, which in cases where the data is stored and processing is not *real-time* can easily be compensated for by subtracting half the window width from the timing:

[image]

For real-time processing if the lag is critical a more sophisticated IIR filter might be appropriate.  Anyhow a clear threshold can be selected from this data.

In code for the above data set:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int32_t dataset[] = { 0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                             0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,
                             0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                             0,-10,-15,-5,20,25,50,-10,-20,-30,0,30,5,-5,
                             0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                             0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0} ;

#define DATA_LEN (sizeof(dataset)/sizeof(*dataset))
#define WINDOW_WIDTH 4
#define THRESHOLD 15 
int main()
{
    uint32_t window[WINDOW_WIDTH] = {0} ;
    int window_index = 0 ;
    int window_sum = 0 ;
    bool spike = false ;

    for( int s = 1; s < DATA_LEN ; s++ )
    {
        uint32_t diff = abs( dataset[s] - dataset[s-1] ) ;
        window_sum -= window[window_index] ;
        window[window_index] = diff ;
        window_index++ ;
        window_index %= WINDOW_WIDTH ;
        window_sum += diff ;

        if( !spike && window_sum >= THRESHOLD )
        {
            spike = true ;
            printf( "Spike START @ %d\n", s - WINDOW_WIDTH / 2 ) ;
        }
        else if( spike && window_sum < THRESHOLD )
        {
            spike = false ;
            printf( "Spike END @   %d\n", s - WINDOW_WIDTH / 2 ) ;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Spike START @ 66
Spike END @   82
```

https://onlinegdb.com/ryEw69jJH

Comparing the original data with the detection threshold gives:

[image]

For your real data, you will need to select a suitable window width and threshold to get the desired result, both of which will depend on the bandwidth and amplitude of the disturbances you wish to detect.

Also you may need to guard against arithmetic overflow if your samples are of sufficient magnitude.  They need to be less than 2<sup>32</sup> / *window-width* to guarantee no overflow in the integrator.  Alternatively you could use floating-point or `uint64_t` for the `window` type, or add code to deal with *saturation*.

Answer (score 3):

You could look at statistical analysis. Calculating the standard deviation over the data set and then checking when your data goes out of bound.

You can choose to do this in two way's; either you use a running average over a fixed (relatively small) number of samples or you take the average over the whole data set. As I see multiple spikes in your set I would suggest the first. This way you can possibly stop processing (and later continue) every time you find a spike.

For your purpose you do not really need to calculate the standard deviation sigma. You could actually leave it at the squared of sigma. This will give you a slight performance optimization not having to calculate the square root.

Some pseudo code:

```
// The data set.
int x[N];   

// The number of samples in your mean and std calculation.
int M <= N;  

// Simga at index i over the previous M samples.
int sigma_i = sqrt( sum( pow(x[i] - mean(x,M), 2) ) / M );

// Or the squared of sigma 
int sigma_squared_i = sum( pow(x[i] - mean(x,M), 2) ) / M;
```

The disadvantage of this method is that you need to set a threshold for the value of sigma at which you trigger. However it is very safe to say that when setting the threshold at 4 or 5 times your average sigma you will have an usable system.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get a working algorithm. Basically, determine the average difference between data points. If my data starts to exceed some multiple of that value consecutively then most likely there is a spike occurring.

Comment: There is seldom a need to calculate an average - the sum is enough and does not discard information through rounding.  It seems like what you have proposed is the "_moving average of the differential_", I suggest the moving sum.